# If there are examples of good music that break out of the "4 measures" mold?

Tags: rhythm, time-signatures

Tool does a great job of stepping out of the 4/4 time signature, like in their [33/16 pneuma](https://www.reddit.com/r/ToolBand/comments/cyt3ui/pneuma_rhythmtime_signature/) song. However, they still (for the most part) play 4 *measures* of this 33/16, or 8 or some multiple of 4. Why not 3 or 5 or 7 or something, 6 even? Does anyone have examples of good music that has this feature and breaks out of the "4 measures" mold? Not talking about classical music that is all over the place, but something that explicitly has 3 or 5 or 6 or 7 or something like that, *measures*, of any time signature. By "good" I mean music that people actually like, not just purely experimental music that accomplishes this but doesn't sound enjoyable.

Comment: If by "people" you mean the entire population of the world, then you'll have to stick with 4 bar blocks. But if "people" means enough to win countless Grammy awards, check out Pat Metheny and Pat Metheny Group.

Comment: Dagnabbit, classical music doesn't count. Otherwise, I'd cite Brahms's Rhapsody in E Flat Major, Op. 119, No. 4 and its heavy use of 5-bar phrases along with the 2nd movement of Beethoven's 9th Symphony and his explicit instructions for the *conductor* to conduct with 3-bar phrases.

Comment: If I think of any video game music examples that don't use 4-bar phrases for any significant stretches of time, I'll let you know. Oddly, all I can come up with right now are video game music in mixed meter but with mainly 4-bar phrases and other video game music that sometimes uses different phrase lengths but often reverts to 4-bar phrases.

Comment: It's a good question, and I suspect the answer has to do with the fact that most of us enjoy the feeling of being able to predict where music is going, and that feeling is simplest with divisions of two.  Three is a bit more effort, four is as good as two, five is a lot harder, and so forth.  Just my humble opinion.

Comment: There are countless examples of odd phrase lengths and/or odd meters in pop/rock music and musical theater. Whether they are good or not is entirely opinion based.

Comment: Even ifyou leave out "Classical,"  there's jazz,  old-time, new-age,... dozens of non-pop categories.

Comment: Three weeks late - but would 12 Days of Christmas count?

Comment: @Tim, ha! good example.

Comment: @LancePollard, try rewording the "good music" part and make it more objective, then I think your worthwhile question will be reopened.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis The bigger problem is finding examples of songs is off-topic it ends up with an endless list of songs that can fit. This is a good example why it doesn't work as I can list 10s or 100s off the top of my head and there are countless.

Comment: So would "does popular music use uneven phrase lengths?" be OK simply because it does not ask for answers to include examples of real music?

Comment: It would be better, but at this point it would invalidate several answers especially the ones that already reference "good music"

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Good idea: one person's good music is another's unbearable noise; one person's genre that doesn't count is another's good music.

Comment: @Dom "Identify this particular tune" is off-topic because it is too specific and would help few if any future readers. Fine. So how come "Name examples of pieces that fit this broad criterion" off-topic? This site would limit itself too much if we have to walk a tightrope between "too specific" and "too broad".

Comment: @RosieF because it's in general a bad fit on Q&A sites to have questions with unbound lists. There are always more answers you can add and there's not a definitive answer. Every answer is equally valid as long as it fits the criteria, voting does not signal much on the questions outside a popularity contest for the example(s) themselves. They also tend to attract single answer song + link which typically get flagged as low quality answers.

Comment: Personally I find Stack Exchange to be a perfectly fine place for lists, and for questions with no single definitive answer - though of course it's up to us whether we want them here.

Comment: Why exactly is "examples" being twisted to mean "a list"? A few examples to support an answer are _perfectly fine_. That's basic intellectual rigor. List request are when someone is too lazy to research, like: "what are some good method books for practicing my scales?"

Comment: If a person were to answer "yes, there are songs with uneven phrase lengths" ...and then can't produce even one example, it's a waste of time.

Comment: just for comparison, this https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33102/are-there-any-popular-pieces-which-periodically-modulate-down is essentially the same type of question - request for examples of music with a particular characteristic - but it wasn't closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will satisfy the "good music" requirement...

[image]

...*Yesterday* by The Beatles famously has a seven bar phrase length.

"Examples" is plural, so at least one more...

[image]

...*Eleanor Rigby* by The Beatles uses a five bar phrase length.

Notice that both examples are *phrase lengths* of *uneven counts* in common time.

It's not part of the question, but I think it's interesting to look at who the various phrase lengths are produces.

In *Yesterday* I think the lyric can be broken up like 1+2+2+2 to get the seven bars. Each line - "all my trouble seemed so far away", "now it looks as though there here to stay", and "oh, I believe in yesterday" - is an even two bars. In front of all that is a single, introductory word - "yesterday", "suddenly" which only needs one bar of time. So it's composed of even unit and a one bar prefix.

In the *Eleanor Rigby* case the lyrical line is four bars extended with a repetition - "...no one will hear, no one comes near" - which extended a four bar length with one extra bar. So this one too is composed of even unit, but the one bar added to make it uneven is a suffix.

> ...Not talking about classical music ...not just purely experimental music

It seems the premise behind the question is: music with uneven phrase lengths is *not accessible* by some common audience standard. I don't think that is the case based on real examples from "popular" music. I also don't think that music with odd time signatures is inaccessible.

A lot of "experimental" band like to use uneven counts. But I don't think there is anything inherently inaccessible about uneven counting. For example, 7/4 is used in some kinds of folk music which seems to me *categorically* not experimental, not un-popular. Other examples could be given. When an experimental band uses uneven counts to make inaccessible music I think the inaccessible nature comes from other factors ...like tedious guitar and drum solos, dissonant harmonies, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether you mean to exclude all classical music or only classical music that employs irregular meter.  In case it is the latter, I offer this example:

There is a lovely trio sonata by Buxtehude (opus 1, number 4) whose first movement is a chaconne built on a three and a half measure long bass.

Comment: Isn't this a "classical" example which the OP wants to exclude?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis perhaps I misunderstood the meaning of "all over the place," but I took it to mean music with irregular meter (Stravinsky comes to mind).  So I thought that classical music that *isn't* "all over the place" metrically would be of interest, including this example.

Comment: Hmm, now that I re-read the OP's line about "classical", I don't really understand what he is after in terms of style/genre.

Answer (score 0):

Las ketchup's "Aserejé", which has been a super-mega-hit back in the early 00s, does runs of six measures during the chorus. Not sure if this qualifies as "good music", but surely is a non overtly experimental thing, and people found it enjoyable back then.

Answer (score 0):

[Moonlight In Vermont](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_in_Vermont_(song)) has a 6 bar A section. Also many popular songs (I Got Rhythm for instance) have a 2 bar "tag" towards the end which breaks up the usual 4 bar thing a bit.